# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'const char*&' from an rvalue of type 'const char *'

Tags: c++, reference, constants, reference-binding

i made a mystrcpy function,

```
void mystrcpy(char *&stuff, const char *&otherstuff){
    for(int i=0; stuff[i]&&other[i]; i++){
        stuff[i]=other[i];
    }
}
```

and a main function:

```
int main(){
    char *hello="hello";
    mystrcpy(hello, "bye bye"/*<--i have no clue what data type this really is!!*/);
    printf("%s\n", hello);
    return 0;
}
```

it does not compile, and says "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'const char*&' from an rvalue of type 'const char *'"...

when i just do:

```
const char *bye="bye bye";
mystrcpy(hello, bye);
```

it compiles without error.

i need to know why the former one doesnt work, thanks.

Comment: loose the & in the function signature, they do not add anything.

Comment: And `char *hello="hello";` ??? Even if you do get this to compile it's going to puke on an invalid-write to read-only memory in your function. If the aforementioned line compiles without at *least* a warning you seriously need to turn up your warning levels to pedantic elevations.

Comment: @hoholee12: Well, first and foremost, why are your parameters passed *by reference*??? There are many ways to "fix" your code. which is why it is pointless without knowing your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function takes *a reference to a pointer*, which is a bit unusual. Notably, this means that the input must be a pointer that has its own storage (so that you can take a reference to the pointer).

`const char *bye="bye bye"; mystrcpy(hello, bye);` works because `bye` is a pointer variable, so you can take a reference to it.

`mystrcpy(hello, "bye bye")` fails because `"bye bye"` is *not* a pointer - it's an array of characters (a `const char [8]`) and so there's no pointer to take a reference to.

You do not need the reference `&` in your `mystrcpy` function signature - that simply makes the function harder to use, and can introduce interesting bugs if you accidentally adjust the pointers in the function (e.g. if you started doing `*stuff++ = *other++;`).

Answer (score 2):

"bye bye" is no pointer but an array of characters. It can decay to a pointer, but it is not possible to pass it as a reference to a pointer.

You might change the function signature:

```
void mystrcpy(char *stuff, const char *otherstuff)
```

If you want to inspect a type at compile time, you might use a static assertion generating a compiler error:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void inspect_type(T&)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, void>::value, "inspect_type");
}

int main()
{
    inspect_type("bye bye");
}
```

g++ gives:

> In instantiation of ‘void inspect_type(const T&) [with T = const char [8]]’
>   ...

Comment: so, its not a 'const char*' ?

Comment: @hoholee12 it *converts* to `const char*`, natively it is not `const  char*` and as such a reference to said-same is not plausible.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I'd call it "an array of literals". It's an array that's a literal. Are the component `char`s "literals"? Not sure. Don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

`const char *&` is a non-`const` reference to a `char const *`. The type of `"bye bye"` is `char const[8]` (the size includes the terminating null character). Your call to `mystrcpy` will implicit convert (or *decay*) the `char const [8]` to a `char const *`, but that produces an rvalue pointer, which you cannot bind to a non-`const` reference parameter.

If you change your function signature to

```
void mystrcpy(char *&, const char * const&)
//                                  ^^^^^ const reference
```

your code will compile. Similarly, if you take the pointer(s) by value, your code will compile

```
void mystrcpy(char *, const char *)
```

---

Once you fix all that, your code will compile and probably crash at runtime, because you have undefined behavior.

```
char *hello="hello";
```

C++11 forbids you from converting a string literal to a `char *`, and it was deprecated behavior in C++03. Not only that, but your `mystrcpy` call then attempts to overwrite the string literal, which is again undefined behavior.

Turn up your compiler's warning level, and pay attention to the warnings. g++ produces the following warning for the line above with `-pedantic`

> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
>
> ```
>  char *hello="hello";
>              ^
> ```